# How to block the Textbox textchanged event fire in asp.net when a javascript confirm box's cancel button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am having one textbox having autopostback=true. It fires the textchanged event and performs some functionality when value is entered into the textbox. I need to put one confirm prompt in javascript and fire the textchanged event only when "OK" button will click. "Cancel" click will block the textchange event fire of the textbox.

Comment: You'll get better, faster answers if you provide your code.

Comment: Try this onchange="return confirm()". In the confirm function you can return true or false. I guess false will prevent the default action.